The diameter of the union of two sets in a metric space cannot exceed the sum of the diameters of the two sets and the distance between them
Let $A$ and $B$ be any two (nonempty) sets in a metric space $(X, d)$. Then how to show that
$$
d (A \cup B) \leq d(A) + d(B) + d(A, B)?   \tag{0} 
$$
Here we have the following definitions:
For any (nonempty) set $S$ in a metric space $(X, d)$, the diameter $d(S)$ is given by
$$
d(S) := \sup \big\{ d(x, y) \colon x \in S, y \in S \big\}. \tag{1} 
$$
And, for any (nonempty) sets $S$ and $T$ in the metric space $(X, d)$, the distance $d(S, T)$ between $S$ and $T$ is given by
$$
d(S, T) := \inf \big\{ d(s, t) \colon s \in S, t \in T \big\}. \tag{2}
$$
Intuitively, we can visualise two circles or two rectangles in the Euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$.
My Attempt:
Let $x$ and $y$ be any points in $A \cup B$. Then we have the following two cases according as both $x$ and $y$ are in the same set or are in different sets.
Case 1. If both $x$ and $y$ are in the same set, we can assume without any loss of generality that $x, y \in A$. Then we have
$$
\begin{align}
d(x, y) &\leq d(A) \qquad \mbox{ [ because $d(A)$ is an upper bound on these distances ] } \\
&\leq d(A) + d(B) + d(A, B). \qquad \mbox{ [ because the quantity $d(B) + d(A, B)$ is non-negative ] } \\
\end{align}
$$
Similarly, if $x, y \in B$, then we also have
$$
d(x, y) \leq d(A) + d(B) + d(A, B). \tag{3} 
$$
Case 2. If $x$ and $y$ are in different sets, we can assume without loss of generality that $x \in A$ and $y \in B$. For any point $a \in A$ we have
$$
d(x, a) \leq d(A), \tag{4} 
$$
because $d(A)$ is an upper bound on distances between points of set $A$,
and, similarly for any point $b \in B$ we have
$$
d(b, y) \leq d(B). \tag{5}
$$
Moreover, for any real number $\epsilon > 0$ we can choose points $a_\epsilon \in A$ and $b_\epsilon \in B$ such that
$$
d \left( a_\epsilon, b_\epsilon \right) < d(A, B) + \epsilon, \tag{6}
$$
because $d(A, B)$ is the infimum (i.e. the greatest lower bound) on distances between points in set $A$ and points in set $B$.
Therefore using (4), (5), and (6) above we have
$$
\begin{align}
& \ \ \ d(x, y) \\ 
&\leq d\left(x, a_\epsilon \right) + d\left(a_\epsilon, b_\epsilon \right) + d\left(b_\epsilon, y\right) \qquad \mbox{[ by the triangle inequality ] } \\
&\leq d(A) + d(A, B) + \epsilon + d(B) \qquad \mbox{ [ by (4), (5), and (6) above ] } \\ 
&= d(A) + d(B) + d(A, B) + \epsilon. 
\end{align}
$$
Is what I have done so far correct? If so, then how to complete the proof from this point on?
Or, is there a more optimal proof of this result?
PS:
Thus we have shown that, for all $x \in A$ and $y \in B$, we have
$$
d(x, y) \leq d(A) + d(B) + d(A, B) + \epsilon, \tag{7} 
$$
and from Case 1 (7) also holds when $x, y \in A$ or when $x, y \in B$. We can thus conclude that, for all $x, y \in A\cup B$, (7) holds. Therefore we have
$$
\sup \big\{ d(x, y) \colon x \in A \cup B, y \in A \cup B \big\}  \leq d(A) + d(B) + d(A, B) + \epsilon,
$$
that is,
$$
d(A \cup B) \leq d(A) + d(B) + d(A, B) + \epsilon,
$$
and since this last inequality holds for every real number $\epsilon > 0$, we must also have
$$
d(A \cup B)  \leq d(A) + d(B) + d(A, B),
$$
as required.
Have I managed to correctly and accurately complete the required proof? Or, are there still issues with my proposed proof?

The fancy trick is to show that $d(A\cup B)< d(A)+d(B)+d(A,B)+\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0.$

to conclude, take the supremum over $x$ and $y$ in $A\cup B$, then let $\varepsilon \to 0$.
